# wanted to select a specific fields from the database using python where the required field name is entered by the user

Tags: python, sqlite, user-input

the matter is i have an user input which is a field name and i wanted to select the field in my database having the same name that is entered by the user.

the environment is python and the database software is sqlite so suggest according to it

```
name = input("enter the field to be selected = ")
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM events",(name,))
print("available categories are:")
options = cur.fetchall()
print(options)
```

i have tried this but this does not works as i wanted.
can anyone suggest a way to achieve what i am trying.

And if possible help me to do the same when a table name is entered from the user and i wanted to select the corresponding table in my database.
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output or error you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: enter the field to be selected = category_id
available categories are:
[('category_id',)] this is the output i am getting but instead of it i want all the items of that column to be selected and fetched

Comment: Probably something went wrong when the table were populated. All the values of the category_id field seem to be "category_id".

Comment: i have checked the data there is no mistake in it they have many different values. Actually the problem is that it is either fetching or selecting or doing something and at the last gives the same string which is entered by the user.